# Remove and terminate all tasks from AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to run a number of AsyncTask's on AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.
I am using the following code.

```
Tasks[i].executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
                                                              taskParams);
```

After certain number of threads was sent to the executor, it no longer accepts new AsyncTasks. (I do not see any errors, but doInBackGroundMethod is not started for some reason).

I suspect this happens because it's pool is full.
Is there any way to reset the executor?
I want to completely terminate all the tasks so that it will start to accept new tasks again and process them immediately.

I tried to terminate the Tasks using their *cancel* method, but it didn't help.

Comment: Why don't you create your own pool instead? AsyncTask is really not ideal for fine-grained control. (See the Executors class.) That said, if you have well-behaving tasks and have references to them, you can just cancel() the tasks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your tasks finishing? Are you handling the apropriate exceptions? How many tasks are you creating?

Keep in mind that `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` (at least in [API 17](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html); this doc page has a bunch of useful details), is set up with

```java
public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE, TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);
```

Where `CORE_POOL_SIZE` is 5 and `MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE` is 128.

The sPoolWorkQueue with

```java
private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);
```

This means that the queue has a maximum capacity of 10 items.

The THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR keeps at least 5 threads alive. As tasks are added, they are added to the queue. When the queue fills, then new threads will be spawned, up to 128 (there are other limitations tho).

When this happens (128 threads, the max, are running and the queue is full) then any new tasks will be rejected, and handled with the default handler (since it's not being set explicitly, is `AbortPolicy`), which throws a [RejectedExecutionException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionException.html).

Make sure that you're not just catching and not handling such exceptions.

One way to deal with this is to create your own [ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (even if it's just your instance of ThreadPoolExecutor with different parameters) and configure the parameters that fit your situation best. Parameters like the queue (you can control the amount of items it can hold, or if it's unbounded, etc) or how to handle rejected tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two reasons to having cancelled AsyncTasks still running:

- Either you don't call `cancel` with `mayInterruptIfRunning` set to `true`
- Either you do call `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` but the `InterruptedException` is miss-handled by the executed code: Make sure your code (and the possible subsequent calls to libraries) don't obfuscate/silence `InterruptedException`s by a try/catch on `InterruptedException`s or even on `Exception`.